# Node: is Express-validator isString() necessary?

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I'm using Node/Express/Express-Validator and all my request variables are coming in as strings to the server.

But doesn't that make certain checks irrelevant? Like 'isString()' below?

```
router.post('/create/company', multer().none(), [
    body('companyName')
    .isString()
    .withMessage('Please enter a string')
    .isLength({ min: 1, max: 50 })
    .withMessage('Enter a company name between 1 and 50 characters')
], adminController.createCompany);
```

Sorry if it's obvious, but I hadn't really thought about it until I started testing my routes and now I'm wondering if I should even check? There's also obviously a gap in my knowledge here, just wondering what I'm missing!

Thanks

Comment: “*all my request variables are coming in as strings to the server.*” Sure, they’re strings *right now*, in *your* testing. What types will you receive once this server hits production? (Hint: you won’t know until it’s deployed what crazy data Internet users will hit your server with.)

Comment: Hi @esqew - that's what I thought - but when I pass a variable as say an int it's being serialized, no? it seems to be hitting my route as a string, and therefore not triggering the `isString()` condition (obviously that doesn't make much sense outside of testing, but I hope you understand what I mean!)

Comment: Think the confusion was partly a lack of understanding on my part, and not knowing exactly what the other `express-validator` methods were doing. `FormData` appears to always have numbers processed as strings on the server, `application/json` does not. But I think the `trim()` and `escape()` methods chained before `isString()` have been converting the number to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's probably just an oversight on my part (although I can't see anything about it anywhere in the docs), but just in case it helps anyone else, in my actual code I was chaining `escape()` and `trim()` before `isString()`, and these were converting the number to a string.